# GridView lags on Galaxy s 4

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview, universal-image-loader

I have a GridView with this item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_library_cover"
    layout="@layout/view_document_cover" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_library_cover_lbw"
    layout="@layout/view_document_cover_lbw"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_library_cover_journal"
    layout="@layout/view_document_cover_journal"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_library_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_info_blue" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> view_document_cover.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_cover_normal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/document_cover_space_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="280"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/document_cover_space_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="11" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/document_cover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="389"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/document_cover_space_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/document_cover_fg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/fg_cover_normal" />
```

> view_document_cover_lbw.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_cover_lbw" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/document_cover_space_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="280"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/document_cover_space_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="15" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/document_cover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="385"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/document_cover_space_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="26" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/document_cover_fg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/fg_cover_lbw" />
```

> view_document_cover_journal.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_cover_normal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/document_cover_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/document_cover_space_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="280"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/document_cover_space_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="11" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/document_cover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="389"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/document_cover_space_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/document_cover_fg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/fg_cover_normal" />
```

I know that using nested weights is bad but read further.

Here's my `getView()` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Document item = (Document) getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(RESOURCE_ID, parent, false);
    View normalCover = ViewHolder.get(convertView,
            R.id.grid_item_library_cover);
    View lbwCover = ViewHolder.get(convertView,
            R.id.grid_item_library_cover_lbw);
    View journalCover = ViewHolder.get(convertView,
            R.id.grid_item_library_cover_journal);
    ImageView coverView;
    switch (item.getDocumentType()) {
    case 1:
        lbwCover.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        normalCover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        journalCover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        coverView = ViewHolder.get(lbwCover, R.id.document_cover);
        break;
    case 3:
        lbwCover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        normalCover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        journalCover.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        coverView = ViewHolder.get(journalCover, R.id.document_cover);
        break;
    default:
        lbwCover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        normalCover.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        journalCover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        coverView = ViewHolder.get(normalCover, R.id.document_cover);
    }
    if (item.isCoverDownloaded()) {
        ImageManager.displayCover(
                "file://" + mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)
                        + File.separator + "documents" + File.separator
                        + item.getDocumentId() + File.separator
                        + "cover.png", coverView, item.getDocumentType());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

I'm using Universal Image Loader to load images from file. Here're it's settings:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            context).defaultDisplayImageOptions(options).build();

public static void displayCover(String uri, ImageView view, int type) {
    DisplayImageOptions.Builder optionsBuilder = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(500, true, true, false))
            .delayBeforeLoading(200);
    switch (type) {
    case 1:
        optionsBuilder.preProcessor(new MaskedPreProcessor(
                R.drawable.mask_cover_lbw));
        optionsBuilder.showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.mask_cover_lbw);
        break;
    case 3:
        optionsBuilder.preProcessor(new MaskedPreProcessor(
                R.drawable.mask_cover_journal));
        optionsBuilder.showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.mask_cover_journal);
        break;
    default:
        optionsBuilder.preProcessor(new MaskedPreProcessor(
                R.drawable.mask_cover_normal));
        optionsBuilder.showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.mask_cover_normal);
    }

    sLoader.displayImage(uri, view, optionsBuilder.build());
}
```

I need to preprocess the bitmap cause I need to apply alpha mask on it.

The issue is that it works OK on Motorola XOOM but incredibly lags on Samsung Galaxy S4 (i9505, Android 4.3) on scrolling if any image is displayed in `GridView`. It lags even if I remove nested weight and use only top level weighted LinearLayout. It lags even if I set Image in xml not through UIL. But if there is no image - it scrolls smoothly. Also using UIL i often get warning:

> 02-25 15:39:55.280: W/OpenGLRenderer(23029): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (4608x321, max=4096x4096)

While my images are 372*528 pixels.

I use nested weights cause I need to positionate my image relative to two other images in layout independently to pixel density and resolution. While I have fixed number of columns in `GridView` (it's set to 3) I can't use dp values here cause images sizes will differ from device to device. And I need to have exactly the same layout on any.

So how can I achieve that?

Comment: There is not specific solution for your problem. I recommend that you read the following article. It will clarify alot. Link: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html

Also, don't load images when your ListView is Flings.

Comment: @DroidBender the issue is that UIL already loading images in background thread. I also use ViewHolder implementation - that's why I put all 3 cover view layouts into griditem layout (to make it's reusage available). And it doesn't lag on my old Motorola XOOM. But on SGS 4 when any image is loaded to the view by UIL it starts lagging. By the way how not to load images when ListView flings?

Comment: I think you could solve your problem loading images while user is scrolling, so you load the required images, instead of all, and the bitmap to large is an error that the phone is looking for a less resolution image and can't find it but throw and error cuz can't load the current cuz too big.

Comment: @LuisAlberto these images are not in resource folder, they're somwhere on the phone. They all have the same and fixed resolution which is much lesser then limit.

Comment: @Lingviston i think there is an image that pass the limit the error says: max  = (4096x4096) , and there's one image that is = (4608x321). It seems theres one with above max resolution

Comment: @LuisAlberto no, I chcked all of the images I use and they all have the same resolution about 370*520 pixels. Also while I'm using the same images all the time sometimes there're no warnings and all images are shown. But sometimed no images shown at all.

Comment: I've been thinking about your problem and i think you will have to shrink the image according to the device's opengl max resolution, like google did with google maps

Comment: @LuisAlberto I've said many times my images many times smaller then maxiimum bitmap size. If I load the same images not via UIL there's no warnings.

Comment: Samsung devices have little heap space so inflating a lot of images at the same time will cause memory issues very quickly. Keep that in mind .

Comment: @DroidBender 140 mb. And it's not reached.